# Under which conditions on $\beta$ is $y(t)=cos(\beta t) $ a solution?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Let $ y'' + (\frac{k}{m})y = 0 $

a) Under which conditions on $\beta$ is $y(t)=cos(\beta t) $ a solution?
$$
-\cos(\beta t)+\frac{k}{m}\cos(\beta t) = \cos(\beta t)(-1-\frac{k}{m})
$$

If I want  $\cos(\beta t)(-1-\frac{k}{m})=0$, then I seek the numbers in which $\cos(\beta t)=0$. Then $\beta t$ should be a multiple of $\frac{\pi}{2}$ or $\frac{3\pi}{2}$. I don't think that this answer is totally complete. I don't know if that is the conditions rquired for $\beta$ only, or $\beta t$ .

b) which is the initial point in $t=0$ that corresponds to this solution?

I don't know. any clue?

c) In terms of k and m, which is the period of this solution?

I have that $T_0 = \frac{2\pi}{w_0} $= $\frac{2\pi}{\sqrt\frac{k}{m}}$. Is this correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Your differentiation is a bit wrong. The following step is wrong:

> $$-\cos(\beta t)+\frac{k}{m}\cos(\beta t) = \cos(\beta t)(-1-\frac{k}{m})$$

Actually, $y''=-\beta^2 \cos(\beta t)$

So the expression becomes:

$$-\beta^2 \cos(\beta t)+\frac{k}{m}\cos(\beta t) = 0$$
or, $$\cos(\beta t)(-\beta^2+\frac{k}{m})=0$$

This implies $\beta^2=\frac{k}{m}$ which is the necessary condition.

2. At $t=0$, $y(0)=1$
3. The expression is correct and follows from the correction in the first part as I have proposed.

Answer (score 1):

we get $$-\cos(\beta t)\beta^2+\frac{k}{m}\cos(\beta t)=0$$

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**

I think you missed a subtle arithmetic effect. If $y(t) = \cos(\beta t)$ then $y''(t) = -\beta^2 \cos(\beta y)$...

Answer (score 0):

You differentiated wrong. It should be:

$$-\beta^2\cos(\beta t)+\frac{k}{m}\cos(\beta t)=0$$

Divide by $\cos(\beta t)$ to get:

$$-\beta^2+\frac{k}{m}=0$$

Or $\beta=\sqrt{\frac{k}{m}}$

For part b, note that $y(0)=1$ so...

For part c, you are right but I don't know how you got that $\omega=\sqrt{\frac{k}{m}}$ without doing the first part correctly.

Comment: I found a formula in a book for the "natural period of a simple harmonic oscillation". It was $T_0=\frac{2\pi}{w_o}$ with $w_0^2=\frac{k}{m}$